# Android studio2.3.3 - file path

Tags: android

I have created a file in android studio with some text in it. But I'm not able to point out where my file is actually in file explorer of emulator. To confirm the file has been created. Could some body help me?

Comment: Consider sharing your code so others could get better understanding of the problem.

Comment: In project navigator (left panel) right-click on file and select "Show in file explorer"

Comment: Improved grammer

Comment: @dima I tried but I dint see the file which I created

Comment: @oviyarajan in same pane at the top change "Android" to "Project"

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int REQUEST_ID_READ_PERMISSION = 100;
private static final int REQUEST_ID_WRITE_PERMISSION = 200;

private final String fileName = "note.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
    readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_read);
    listButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_list);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            askPermissionAndWriteFile();
        }

    });


    readButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            askPermissionAndReadFile();
        }

    });

    listButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            listExternalStorages();
        }

    });
}

private void askPermissionAndWriteFile() {
    boolean canWrite = this.askPermission(REQUEST_ID_WRITE_PERMISSION,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    //
    if (canWrite) {
        this.writeFile();
    }
}

private void askPermissionAndReadFile() {
    boolean canRead = this.askPermission(REQUEST_ID_READ_PERMISSION,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    //
    if (canRead) {
        this.readFile();
    }
}

// With Android Level >= 23, you have to ask the user
// for permission with device (For example read/write data on the device).
private boolean askPermission(int requestId, String permissionName) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

        // Check if we have permission
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissionName);


        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // If don't have permission so prompt the user.
            this.requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{permissionName},
                    requestId
            );
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


// When you have the request results
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    //
    // Note: If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
    if (grantResults.length > 0) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_READ_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    readFile();
                }
            }
            case REQUEST_ID_WRITE_PERMISSION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    writeFile();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


private void writeFile() {

    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // ==> /storage/emulated/0/note.txt
    String path = extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    Log.i("ExternalStorageDemo", "Save to: " + path);

    String data = editText.getText().toString();

    try {
        File myFile = new File(path);
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(data);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readFile() {

    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // ==> /storage/emulated/0/note.txt
    String path = extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    Log.i("ExternalStorageDemo", "Read file: " + path);

    String s = "";
    String fileContent = "";
    try {
        File myFile = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(fIn));

        while ((s = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            fileContent += s + "\n";
        }
        myReader.close();

        this.textView.setText(fileContent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fileContent, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```